# Laravel date format validation dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: validation, date, laravel-5, format

A simple thing, please help me out. I want to validate date format(dd/mm/yyyy). 
**If my input is 05/02/1991 or 5/2/1991 it should return** **'true'** but

```
 public function rules()
  {
    return [
        'date_of_birth'         => 'required|date_format:"d/m/Y"'
    ];
  }
```

in the above rule it returns **true** only for **05/02/1991** . I need to match both of them.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `date` and `regex` to handle that as `date_format` can handle only one format:

```
<?php

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'date_of_birth' => 'required|date|regex:/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `date` validator takes only one date format as parameter. In order to be able to use multiple formats, you'll need to build a custom validation rule. And it's pretty simple. To be able to use multiple date formats in a single validator You can define the multi-format date validation in your AppServiceProvider with the following code:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider  
{
 public function boot()
 {
    Validator::extend('date_multi_format', function($attribute, $value, $formats) {
        // iterate through all formats
        foreach($formats as $format) {

            // parse date with current format
            $parsed = date_parse_from_format($format, $value);

            // if value matches given format return true=validation succeeded 
            if ($parsed['error_count'] === 0 && $parsed['warning_count'] === 0) {
              return true;
            }
          }

     // value did not match any of the provided formats, so return false=validation failed
     return false;
    });
  }
}
```

You can later use this new validation rule like that:

```
'date' => 'date_multi_format:"Y-m-d H:i:s.u","Y-m-d"' //or any other format
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I ran across a similar issue where I had some forms using a Time Picker, and others using the `<input type="time">`. The latter formats as 24-hour time regardless of the format used in the browser.

Following on from @Foysal's answer, you can also now create a Rule object to define your rule, rather than having to extend the validator.

@see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-rule-objects

run `php artisan make:rule DateMultiFormat`

Then in the new Rule object located at `app/Rules`, you can add the same logic.

Accept the acceptable formats in the constructor, then in the `passes()` method, add the logic.

```php
foreach ($this->acceptedFormats as $format) {
    $parsed = date_parse_from_format($format, $value);
    
    if ($parsed['error_count'] === 0 && $parsed['warning_count'] === 0) {
        return true;
    }
}
        
return false;
```

And in your validator class...

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'date' => [
            'required', // or whatever
            new DateMultiFormat(['m/d/Y', 'Y-m-d']),
        ],
        ...
    ];
```

For my use case, I also had to allow for both formats when preparing the form input for persisting in the db.

```php
try {
    $start = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y g:i A', $startString, $locationTimeZone);
} catch (InvalidFormatException $e) {
    $start = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i', $startString, $locationTimeZone);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this validation compare with your validation

```
public function rules()

   return [
      'date_of_birth'         => 'required|date_format:m/d/Y'
    ];
 }
```